# Misma clave suma de valores en diccionarios en Python

Tags: python, diccionarios

```
dicc = {"12857291":400.0,"30083857":500.00,"1417088894":2999.99,"12857291":200.00}

dicc1 = list(dicc.items())
total ={}

for clave, valor in dicc1:
    total[clave] = total.get(clave,0) + float(valor)
```

Salida:{'12857291': 200.0, '30083857': 500.0, '1417088894': 2999.99}
Quiero hacer una suma de todos los valores que tengan la misma clave de diccionario.
No me suma el 1er valor con el ultimo.

Comment: Al añadir los valores verifica si ya existe y si existe actualiza el valor si no existe solo añádelo

Comment: Los diccionarios son tienen relaciones uno a uno, no pueden haber 2 valores por cada clave. Lo que puedes hacer es ir añadiendo los valores uno a uno, y si se repite sumas.

Answer (score 1):

Como te han dicho en los comentarios, los diccionarios son objetos en los que cada clave debe ser **única**. Tu código lo que hace al leer por segunda vez `"12857291"` es actualizar el valor de esa clave, pero no lo suma.

Tus valores iniciales deberían estar en una lista de tuplas, por ejemplo:

```
lista_dicc = [("12857291",400.0),("30083857",500.00),("1417088894",2999.99),("12857291",200.00)]
```

De esta manera, puedes hacer un bucle en el que primero compruebes si el valor existe en el diccionario o no. Si existe, lo sumas al existente, y si no, lo añades:

```
lista_dicc = [("12857291",400.0),("30083857",500.00),("1417088894",2999.99),("12857291",200.00)]

dicc = {}

for i in lista_dicc:
    if i[0] not in dicc:
        dicc[i[0]] = i[1]
    else:
        dicc[i[0]] += i[1]

print(dicc)
```

El output que consigo es justo el diccionario que buscas, con el valor de la clave `"12857291"` incrementado correctamente:

`{'12857291': 600.0, '30083857': 500.0, '1417088894': 2999.99}`